# What can be done for an account with only 9 reputation for the problem "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban, ban

My situation is extremely weird. I never asked questions very frequently in stackoverflow.Most of the time I found an answer to a question just checking the previous posts. I also contributed to the other stackExchange communities as per my capability. 
So I had asked only 5 questions so far in stackoverflow. In one question I received two upvotes.

Recently, I received 2 downvotes in another question. The most probable reason was that the question was related to a open-source GPU software and was not of much value to the whole community and the proper place to ask questions like that should be github. Being not so familiar with the standard guidelines, I asked a very proper question in an improper place.
From that day I came to know that there is such a thing as barring members from asking question(It is not that I asked questions without thinking and putting much effort) and I realized that I can be banned. To find a solution I searched a little bit and I found

"How can I get out of a question ban?

The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received."

So, now as I have only 9 reputation I can not comment or contribute in the community in any other way except editing my question. I tried to edit my questions to elevate it at the level of community standard. But apparently it is not of much use. Now, I am in an extremely weird situation where I do not see any way to make my account active and participate in this very important community.

Would anyone please help me out?

And My important point was that I have so less reputation that I can not even participate in any other way to improve my reputation as I can not comment or answer any question.

Comment: You are currently *not blocked* on Stack Overflow; your block was lifted before you completed your post here. Perhaps you were [rate limited](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) instead?

Comment: not really ... My situation is that I can not comment in anyone else's post to improve my reputation. Before getting any idea about how this community works , I got banned. I do not know whether I even received an warning or not. I had only 9 reputation and I can not participate in the community except editing my own questions which seems to be very elementary to a beginner level programmer like myself.

Comment: And you have asked more than 5 questions; I see 4 deleted posts.

Comment: And let me reiterate: *You are not currently blocked from asking questions*. I am a Stack Overflow moderator, we can see if you are blocked or not. You are not currently blocked.

Comment: I deleted immediately before even anyone answering many of the times as in many of the cases I found an answer.Ok... I understood that it is a serious issue.

Comment: Ok, it seems the automatic ban is lifted. Thank you for your co-operation. I will be more cautious in future.